# Dotnet Cannot Restore Project Correctly While Using Docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I have a .Net webapi project, and I want to dockerize it. Without docker, dotnet sdk(6.0) can restore everything correctly and there is no obstacle for me to publish the app. But when I use docker to do that, it gives me tones of errors with the error codes `CS0246, CS8714, CS0103, CS0535, CS0738`. You can find my project folder structure and relevant information below:

```
    src
     |-->API
     |    |-->API.csproj
     |    |-->Some other stuff
    tools
     |-->Docker
     |    |-->Dockerfile
    docker-compose.yml
```

```
#./src/Docker/Dockerfile

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source

COPY *.sln ./
COPY ./src/API src/API

WORKDIR /src/API
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /src/API

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /src/API
COPY --from=build /src/API ./
EXPOSE 80/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.dll"]
```

```yaml
#./docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: tools/Docker/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5009:5009"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "prod"
```

Answer (score 0):

the .NET 6.0 SDK image is not official yet

you can use some RC version instead
try

```
ARG REPO=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet
FROM $REPO:6.0.0-rc.1-alpine3.14-amd64
```

follow here for updates:
https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk?tab=description

Comment: Thanks but the same issue continues.

Comment: @GökalpÖztürk does it work with .net 5 version?

Comment: @GökalpÖztürk at which stage of the docker file does it fail?

Comment: No it does not. It fails at the last stage, while publishing the app.